# How to get historical values from a SQL table using date functions?

Tags: sql, date, select, ssms, where-clause

I have a table as structured in image. I need to obtain the score for each distinct foreign key for historical dates, that are, 3, 6, 12, and 24 months ago from today.

From the example below, considering today as 2020-06-24, I need to obtain score value for FK=1,2,...n for dates: 2020-02-29, 2019-11-30, 2019-05-31, 2018-05-31.

I may need to run this query every 2 weeks. What query should I use for SSMS?

[image: Table structure]

Answer (score 0):

One option uses `dateadd()` and `emonth()`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    column2 = 1
    and date in (
        eomonth(dateadd(month,  -4, getdate())),
        eomonth(dateadd(month,  -7, getdate())),
        eomonth(dateadd(month, -13, getdate())),
        eomonth(dateadd(month, -25, getdate()))
    )
```